# Customize IdentityServer4 Completing SignIn View or Message

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I'm currently working on a .NET Core 3.1 application including the IdentityServer4 Framework.

I use the IdentityServer4 Quickstart UI and the ASP.NET Identity.

Currently I try to customize the "transition" messages.

When I click the logon button and authenticate my client against IdentityServer4 I always see the following message flickering:

**Completing login...** or **Completing logon state...**

I want to remove it or exchange it with something else.

I searched the whole application but couldn't find it - I doubt it's hidden somewhere in the ASP.NET Identity Framework but I'm really not sure...

Do by any chance someone know where to find/adjust this message??

Comment: Are you using Blazor?

Comment: absolutely, I use a Blazor Wasm hosted client...

Comment: ...but unfortunately I cannot find this area in my Client app either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the source of those strings [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/search?q=completing%2Blogin&unscoped_q=completing%2Blogin) and they seems to be hard-coded.

Comment: Cool thanks! It's indeed the RemoteAuthenticatorView... I see 2 possible solutions: somehow rewrite the used RenderFragment or simply style the outlining html element with css somehow...

Comment: The documentation has a detailed description on how to customize the remoteAuthenticatorView: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-3.1#customize-the-authentication-user-interface